# Notation that x given z is normally distributed

Tags: notation

I am looking for notation stating x given z is normally distributed. The parameters of the normal distribution are unknown/irrelevant and including placeholder parameters in my context will be too confusing. Is the following acceptable?

\begin{equation}
x|z \sim \mathcal{N}
\end{equation}

Comment: That'll do. $(X|Z=z)\sim \mathcal N$ also is OK. But perhaps you could explain why $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (for some unknown mean and variance) is too confusing?

Comment: You can use *any notation you like* provided you define it.  But using almost any notation without definition, even if it seems perfectly clear to you, risks confusing many (or even all) of your readers unless you are very confident about their backgrounds (*e.g.*, they are all students in the same class where a particular notation has been adopted).